# Get all links that contains a specific word in it

Tags: javascript, regex, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get all the links which contain the "discord" word in it, like "https://discord.com", "www.discordapp.com", "discord.me", etc.

My current code kinda works, by I'm looking for something that can do it with fewer steps (like removing the `isDiscordInvite` function).

This is mt current code:

```
const getUrls = (str: string) => {
  const regex = /(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$])/gim;
  return [...str.matchAll(regex)].map((url) => url[0]);
};

const isDiscordInvite = (url: string) => {
  const isServerInvite = /discord/.test(url);

  return isServerInvite;
};

export const getDiscordInvitesFromMessage = (message: string) => {
  const urls = getUrls(message);

  const invites = urls.filter(isDiscordInvite);
};
```

Does anyone know a regex that can get all the links that contain "discord" in it?

### Examples of correct returns

```js
const exampleInput = "This is an input https://discord.com"

const arrayOfUrls = getDiscordUrls(exempleInput) // Do the magic

// arrayOfUrls should have this value and ONLY this value
// arrayOfUrls === ["https://discord.com"]
```

**Obs1:** I need a way ** to get the links**, to can compare then to other things, not just know if there is an invite in a message.

**Obs2:** The links must be extracted directly from a text, not from an anchor element.

Example:

```js
arrayOfUrls.filter(allUrlsStartsWithHttps)
// OR
arrayOfUrls[0] === "www.google.com"
```

Comment: Why are you using regex. If you just want to get everything that matches a word use String .contains(), get the URL as a string then check the string. Where are these URLs coming from?

Comment: What means *"to be able to compare then to other things"*?

Comment: Yes, parsing texts like "This is an invite https://discord.com", and the function should return an array, like `["https://discord.com"]` (with the full link, and only the full link).
Incorrect return: `["https", "https://discord.com"]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Like this:
```
arrayOfUrls.filter(allUrlsStartWithHttps)
OR
arrayOfUrls[0] === "www.google.com"
```

Comment: @RenatoRazal and what is wrong with your current code? Works? Misses something? Does not work?

Comment: It works, but have more than the necessary steps. With the correct regex the getUrls functions will be able to return only the urls that contain "discord" in it, and I could delete the isDiscordInvite function and the urls.filter from the process

Comment: `Does anyone know a regex that can get all the links that contain "discord" in it?` does `/discord/` not work? If you want to match the https and/or ftp can't you just do `/(https|ftp).*?discord.*?/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[^\s/]*discord\S*/gi
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Bcr1df/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      http                     'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      s?                       's' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ftp                      'ftp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      file                     'file'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    www                      'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ftp                      'ftp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\s/]*                  any character except: whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '/' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  discord                  'discord'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S*                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (0 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is such a complete and incredible answer, that if I could, I would give you 2 "right answer" hahaha

Comment: @RenatoRazal One is enough, have a good time of day!